# Formatting the message in Python logging

Tags: python, logging

I would like to understand if it's possible and how is it possible, to modify the message part of a log message, using the Python logging module.

So basically, you can format a complete log as:

```
format = '{"timestamp": "%(asctime)s", "logger_level": "%(levelname)s", "log_message": %(message)s}'
```

However, I would like to make sure the message part is always in json format. Is there any way I can modify the format of only the message part, maybe with a custom `logging.Formatter`?

Thank you.

Comment: That it gets converted to json with a json.dumps() I would expect

Comment: is this not sufficient? - https://github.com/madzak/python-json-logger Or I didnt understood your question correctly

Comment: The problem is that, if the message is a dictionary, it formats it as a whole string, while I would like the whole log to be a json item

Comment: Can you please provide a simple example with both actual and expected output? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @daniel, are you saying that you would like `log["log_message"]` to be a dictionary, instead of a string? (After parsing the log string as json, of course.)

Comment: @alexis Yes, this could work :)

Comment: Then maybe it's enough to use the format I show in my answer?

Comment: As I am mentioning bellow for the answer of Vinay Sajip, this also forces to implicitly format every message before it's passed to the logging module. Is there a way where I can jsonify every message without having to do it for every message that I'm logging?

Answer (score 1):

The format specification `%(message)s` tells Python you want to format a string. Try it with `%(message)r` and it should do the job:

```
>>> logging.error('{"log_message": %r}', {"a": 55})
ERROR:root:{"log_message": {'a': 55}}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's [an example in the Logging Cookbook](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#implementing-structured-logging) which shows one way of doing this.Basically:

```
import json
import logging

class StructuredMessage:
    def __init__(self, message, /, **kwargs):
        self.message = message
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s >>> %s' % (self.message, json.dumps(self.kwargs))

_ = StructuredMessage   # optional, to improve readability

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format='%(message)s')
logging.info(_('message 1', foo='bar', bar='baz', num=123, fnum=123.456))
```

Of course, you can adapt this basic idea to do something closer to what you want/need.

**Update:** The formatting only happens if the message is actually output. Also, it won't apply to logging from third-party libraries. You would need to subclass `Logger` before importing any other modules which `import logging` to achieve that, but it's a [documented approach](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.setLoggerClass).

Comment: However, this requires you to implicitly format every message before it's passed to the logging module. Is it possible that this formatting is apply to all messages without having to say so specifically?